# Google Apps EDU Fireside Chat Hangout: An Introduction to Apps Script - Can't get approve link to save approval in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I watched a youtube video titled "Google Apps EDU Fireside Chat Hangout: An Introduction to Apps Script" where Eric Koleda shows how to do an "Approval" from gmail.

I have copied the code and everything works except the doGet function (see below). The function is suppose to write "yes" in the Approval column of the spreadsheet and then present a web page that writes "The announcement was approved".

Any help is appreciated. see code below.

```
function onFormSubmit(event) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Announcements');
  var title = event.namedValues['Title'];
  var description = event.namedValues['Description'];
  var url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/s/AKfycbxT0T7bdcZ0NGmRHoZuo5onrPol9bMNDK8W4fYWol5gS09xKXk/exec';
  url += '&spreadsheetId=' + spreadsheet.getId();
  url += '&row=' + sheet.getLastRow();
  var message = 'New announcement submitted.\n' +
      'Title: ' + title +
      '\nDescription: ' + description +
      '\nApprove: ' + url;
  MailApp.sendEmail('emailaddress@blahblah.com', 'New Announcement', message);
}


function doGet(event) {
  var spreadsheetId = event.parameter['spreadsheetId'];
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Announcements');
  var row = event.parameter['row'];
  sheet.getRange(row, 3).setValue('Yes');
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var label = app.createLabel();
  label.setText('The announcement was approved');
  app.add(label);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Did you receive an error description ?

Comment: pleinolijf - I receive this error when I click on the url - Google Drive Error - "Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested does not exist. Please check the address and try again."

Answer (score 0):

You'll get that error, "Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested does not exist. Please check the address and try again.", if the user clicking the link isn't part of the domain that the script is running on, in this case "shawinc.com".

Comment: Got it working..notice the differences..instead of this url .... https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/s/AKfycbxT0T7bdcZ0NGmRHoZuo5onrPol9bMNDK8W4fYWol5gS09xKXk/exec                                                              I used this url........https://docs.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/exec?service=AKfycbxT0T7bdcZ0NGmRHoZuo5onrPol9bMNDK8W4fYWol5gS09xKXk